# Retrieve value from customer note (Liquid Shopify)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've added fields to customer registration form like this:

`<label for="CustomerFormAllergies">Allergies</label> <input type="text" id="CustomerFormAllergies" name="customer[note][Allergies]" placeholder="Allergies">`

`<label for="VAT">Tax Number</label> <input type="text" id="VAT" name="customer[note][VAT]" placeholder="Tax number">`

How would I be able to retrieve only one fields value, which is of course part of the customer note? With {{ customer.note }} I get both fields values. I want to only get the part from a specific field, for example the field with "[Allergies]" tag.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out what the value is in all cases? No note, just allergies, just VAT and both. Is there anything in the result the clues you in as to what you can do?

Comment: Yes, the value I get is for example : "Allergies: soundso VAT: 123456". Not really get a clue from this unfortunately.

Comment: So the data your form is collecting is a simple string. You can parse strings, albeit with Liquid it is somewhat primitive. If you added a terminator to your string, like a comma, you could SPLIT on that, and then iterate. Have fun.